# Can't make API calls React Native

Tags: reactjs, api, react-native

I'm having a bit of trouble setting up an API call for authentication in react native. I use the following code:

```
fetch('http://myserver.ngrok.io/auth/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: {
            email: 'email@gmail.com',
            password: 'password',
        },
    })
        .then(() => {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Main');
        })
        .catch(() => {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Auth');
            console.error('Request Failed');
        });
```

I'm using ngrok, because at first, I thought I was having issues with my android emulator/device QR scanning not being able to connect to my computer's localhost. I have tested the api call to this ngrok endpoint in postman, and it has worked perfectly. However, the above code always gives me my `Request Failed`.

I have tested this on both my android emulator and tunneling with my android phone via QR. Is this a syntax issue?

Comment: Use instead `catch(console.log)` so as to inspect and debug what error you're facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to use fetch to send JSON would be in your case:

```
fetch('http://myserver.ngrok.io/auth/login', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
  body: JSON.stringify({
    email: 'email@gmail.com',
    password: 'password',
  }),
})
```

Note the `JSON.stringify` and the header.

Also, fetch will be successful even in case of a server error, and the user could enter invalid credentials, so check the server response before redirecting to main:

```
.then(resp => resp.json())
.then(data => this.props.navigation.navigate(data.correctCredentials ? 'Main' : 'Auth'))
.catch(...)
```